# scanf multiple input from file

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C from an unnamed book that contains the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word[10];
    int i = 0;
    while (scanf("%9s", word) == 1) {
        i = i+1;
        if (i % 2) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", word);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The example is to demonstrate piping the output into separate files by running with

`./thisprogram < input.txt > output.txt 2> error.txt`

and is supposed to output every other word into the respective files.  It seems like it should work, but when I run it only the first word is ever output, and I can't figure out why scanf is only taking the first value.  I'm sure I've copied the code correctly, but there is no errata that list this, so I'm wondering if any of you gurus can explain why it isn't working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` statement shouldn't be in the `while` block but after it:

```
int main() {
    char word[10];
    int i = 0;
    while (scanf("%9s", word) == 1) {
        i = i+1;
        if (i % 2) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", word);
        }
        /* remove this: return 0; */
    }
    return 0; /* place it here */
}
```

Otherwise your program will exit after the extraction of the first word.

Comment: Holy cow, I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have done a very silly mistake.

you have placed the `return statement` inside the `while loop` so your loop runs only once and it gets terminated.

i ran your code on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/678Mb) and found that your code is printing only the first word that you are entering.

place the `return statement` after the `while loop` ends and your code will be corrected.

after correction the code ran successfully as you can see [here](http://ideone.com/5BS7S).

hope this helps.